# python: os.path.join returns a None in an abstract class

Tags: python, file, directory, os.path

i have a directory colors in the data directory and from which i would like to read some files as follows:

```
my_dir
  |__data
  |    |__colors
  |    |    |__light_colors.csv
  |    |    |__dark_colors.csv
  |    |__ages
  |__code
       |__data_reader.py
       |__config.py
```

in my config file i have:

```
import os

REPO_ROOT_DIRECTORY = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
colors_DATA_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(REPO_ROOT_DIRECTORY, "Data")
```

and in my data_reader.py file i have the following code, which is an abstract class.
i have to keep the abstract class, so that one i cannot change:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from config import colors_DATA_DIRECTORY
import os

class PathReader(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def read_data_type(self): pass
    
class colorReader(PathReader):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_to_types = os.path.join(colors_DATA_DIRECTORY, 'colors')

    def read_data_type(self):
        for files in os.listdir(self.path_to_types):
            print (os.path.join(self.path_to_types, files))
```

when i try the following, it also outputs a None at the end, which i do not know why.

```
 g= colorReader()
 print(g.read_data_type())
```

the current output:

```
/Users/k/Desktop/my_dir/data/colors/light_colors.csv
/Users/k/Desktop/my_dir/data/colors/dark_colors.csv
None
```

can someone please tell me where this None is coming from.

**Update:**

ok, i realized what the problem is. the None printed out here is because of the '.ipynb_checkpoints' being created in the colors directory because of some .ipynb file that i had created previously but forgot to remove.

Comment: Please print `self.path_to_types` before `for` and print `files` in your `for` to see what's their values.

Comment: it prints the path as: /Users/k/Desktop/my_dir/data/colors

Comment: What is your `files` values in `for`?

Comment: they are two .csv files in the colors directory

Comment: Is it your complete code? seems `None` has printed from another part of the code.

Comment: yes, this is the complete code. i removed the rest and isolated this part, but i still have this None output at the end, which i do not know where it is coming from